# downloading full page with scrapy

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

i need to crawl a website.
get some of its pages and store them with all of the CSS files and images. exactly like saving the pages in browser.

**i have tried selenium**, but with selenium i can only save the html not full page so it is **not possible** to do this with **selenium**.

1. **i want to know can i do this using Scrapy?**
2. **if it is not possible using Scrapy what else can i use?**

Comment: Please edit the question to identify the experiments/research you have done so far and why they didn't help. The community is far more likely to pick this up if it thinks you'd had a go yourself before coming here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you should be able to do this in scrapy
Inside of the `<head>`tag in the html you should see urls to javascript references in `<script>` tags and you should see `<link>` tags that give you the url to get the css files

Once you get the url, it's a simple matter to do a request in scrapy. The scrapy tutorial shows this:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#a-shortcut-for-creating-requests

These urls contain the raw css or javascript and you can either download that separately or construct a new single HTML document

One thing to note is that the `<script>` tags may contain the full javascript and not a url reference. In this case you'll get the data when you get the html portion